# How to restrict/disable the form view, while click tree view of one2many field in Odoo

Tags: treeview, odoo, formview, odoo-11, one2many

How to restrict/disable the form view, while click the tree view of one2many field in Odoo.

Answer (score 8):

Use style:

```
<field name="your_o2m" style="pointer-events:none;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your field XML definition :

```
<field name="your_o2m" mode="tree" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `no_open` attribute set on the `<tree>` might work

```xml
<field name="o2m_field" widget="one2many" mode="tree">
    <tree no_open="1">
        <field name="name"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```